# how to list data with MySQL query for CI and list only posted employer and job which is not expire

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

Table `users`

```
id     username           password
----------------------------------
1      email@yahoo.com    admin
2      email1@yahoo.com   password
3      example@m.com      admin123
```

Table `employer-profile`

```
id     u_id   company-name       logo
-----------------------------------------
1      2      Blue Rays Graphics logo.jpg
2      1      Hire Me to do best logo.jpg
3      3      example.com        logo.jpg
```

Table `employer-post-job`

```
id     e_id   job-title     job-category    expire date
-------------------------------------------------------
1      2      web-developer IT              2013-9-5
2      1      receptionist  media           2013-9-5
3      2      web-designer  IT              2013-9-5
```

In this table I want to list data in index page like this

```
------------
|          |  Blue Rays Graphics
|   logo   |
|          |
------------

------------
|          |  Hire Me to do best
|   logo   |
|          |
------------
```

Here in this table I want to list employer which job is not expired and if expired all job posted by employer than only hide employer list I want it through mysql query to list in CI Framework.

I tried this

```sql
SELECT *
FROM employer_profile
WHERE u_id IN
        ( SELECT DISTINCT u_id
         FROM employer_profile
         INNER JOIN
             ( SELECT e_id,
                      COUNT(*)
              FROM employer_post_job
              WHERE dead_line >= CURDATE()
              GROUP BY e_id )
         INNER JOIN users ON employer_profile.u_id = users.id);
```

Comment: function employerbyjob() {
  $query ='SELECT * FROM employer_profile 
  WHERE u_id IN (SELECT DISTINCT u_id
  FROM employer_profile
  INNER JOIN employer_post_job
  ON employer_post_job.e_id = employer_profile.u_id
  INNER JOIN users
  ON employer_profile.u_id = users.id)';
  return $this->db->query($query)->result();
 } @Nomi

Comment: i think you need to edit you question with the function that you just wrote, and format it, to get answers @Vijay Rai

Comment: hey @Nomi i edit my question please check and please help to get rid out of it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this query and let me if you still face problem because i can't execute it.

```
Select * from users u 
          inner join employer-profile e ON u.id = e.u_id
          inner join employer-post-job epj ON e.u_id =epj.e_id
          where epj.expire date > '".date('Y-m-d')."'
```

Comment: OR do not use Where clause in the query and use the if condition to check expired jobs using PHP it will do magic.